# jQuery and Chrome... Need another set of eyeballs on this please

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This is weird but I have some autocomplete code that I've customized to only engage when you type the '@' sign... In FireFox it works great. I type one '@' and the dropdown appears.

BUT... when I try it in Chrome, it requires two '@@' to engage the dropdown.

What could this be?

Another strange behavior is that when ad an alert statment, it then actually works when I type one '@' in Chrome... Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Here's the onChange function where I am replacing the @ sign with blank "" so it doesn't show or submit the @ when an item is selected from the dropdown

You can see the @ ascii value is set here as 50 (ATSIGN variable)

```
    var KEY = {
    UP: 38,
    DOWN: 40,
    DEL: 46,
    TAB: 9,
    RETURN: 13,
    ESC: 27,
    COMMA: 188,
    PAGEUP: 33,
    PAGEDOWN: 34,
    BACKSPACE: 8,
    ATSIGN: 50
};
```

Here is a bit of code right before the switch statement

```
    // only opera doesn't trigger keydown multiple times while pressed, others don't work with keypress at all
$input.bind(($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown") + ".autocomplete", function(event) {
    // a keypress means the input has focus
    // avoids issue where input had focus before the autocomplete was applied
    hasFocus = 1;
    // track last key pressed
    lastKeyPressCode = event.keyCode;
```

Then in the switch statement, the autocomplete gets activated only when the @ sign is pressed:

```
        switch(event.keyCode) {

        case KEY.UP:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.prev();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        case KEY.DOWN:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.next();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        case KEY.PAGEUP:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.pageUp();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        case KEY.PAGEDOWN:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( select.visible() ) {
                select.pageDown();
            } else {
                onChange(0, true);
            }
            break;

        // matches also semicolon
        case options.multiple && $.trim(options.multipleSeparator) == "," && KEY.COMMA:
        case KEY.TAB:
        case KEY.RETURN:
            if( selectCurrent() ) {
                // stop default to prevent a form submit, Opera needs special handling
                event.preventDefault();
                blockSubmit = true;
                return false;
            }
            break;

        case KEY.ESC:
            select.hide();
            break;
        case KEY.ATSIGN:
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delay);
            //alert("hi");
            //select.show();
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
```

And here is the function onChange that gets called in the case statement after @ is pressed

```
    function onChange(crap, skipPrevCheck) {
    if( lastKeyPressCode == KEY.DEL ) {
        select.hide();
        return;
    }

    var currentValue = $input.val();

    if ( !skipPrevCheck && currentValue == previousValue )
        return;

    previousValue = currentValue;
    //alert(previousValue);
    currentValue = lastWord(currentValue);
    if ( currentValue.length >= options.minChars) {
        $input.addClass(options.loadingClass);
        if (!options.matchCase)
            currentValue = currentValue.toLowerCase();
            currentValue = currentValue.replace("@","");
            //alert(currentValue);
            request(currentValue, receiveData, hideResultsNow);

    } else {
        stopLoading();
        select.hide();
    }
};
```

As I mentioned, this works great in FF... I press @ once and the autocomplete activates... However in Chrome, I must press @@ (at sign twice)....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you put an alert before the "if (!skipPrevCheck &&) and see if chrome maybe sets the default value so this if reutrns true and returns? It might also be that the timeout produces the delay... just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out... I need to create a new delay variable and make the autocomplete dropdown happen a split second later than the standard time which was 400 ms

So I added the variable delayLong and set it to 500 ms and it works perfectly in Chrome now. Go figure.